# Reference Request: Asymptotic hardness of $hk$ coloring $k$-colorable graphs

Tags: reference-request, approximation-hardness, graph-colouring

I heard of a result in approximate graph coloring, but cannot find the source. The result is:

For every constant $h$ there exists a sufficiently large $k$ such that coloring a $k$-colorable graph with $hk$ colors is NP-hard.

Could someone please point me to the relevant paper?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the references:

- S. Khanna, N. Linial, and S. Safra, [On the hardness of approximating the chromatic number,
  Combinatoria, 20 (2000), pp. 393–415.](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s004930070013)
- C. Lund and M. Yannakakis, [On the hardness of approximating minimization problems, J.
  ACM, 41 (1994), pp. 960–981.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=306789&CFID=239309170&CFTOKEN=77596634)

Answer (score 12):

There are much stronger results for approximate graph coloring.

- S. Khot, [Improved inapproximability results for maxclique, chromatic number and approximate graph coloring.](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/%7Ekhot/papers/maxclique.ps)  show that for all sufficiently large constants $k$ it is NP-hard to color a $k$-colorable graph with $k^{\Omega(\log k)}$ colors
- A very recent result of S. Huang [Improved Hardness of Approximating Chromatic Number](http://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5216) says that for all sufficiently large $k$, it is NP-hard to color a $k$-colorable graphs with $2^{k^{1/3}}$ colors.
- If you are willing to assume Unique Games conjecture (in fact $d$-to-1 conjecture), then I. Dinur, E. Mossel and O. Regev show in [Conditional Hardness for Approximate Coloring](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Edinuri/mypapers/DMR.pdf) that for any $K$ it is hard to color 4-colorable graphs with $K$ colors.
- A follow-up result of I. Dinur and I.Shinkar [On the Conditional Hardness of Coloring a 4-Colorable Graph with Super-Constant Number of Colors](https://sites.google.com/site/igorshinkar/quantDMR.pdf) shows that under some stronger assumptions on the hardness of Unique Games it is hard to color 4-colorable graphs with $\log(n)^{0.001}$ colors, where $n$ is the number of vertices in the graph.

Comment: The last result is interesting, but is there a decimal point mishap there? Two zeros before the decimal is odd...